# Unable to connect to MongoDB. Please make sure mongod is running on mongodb://localhost:27017/mongo-server

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I got this issue when running `index.js`.

Here is my code:

```
var http = require('http'),
    express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    Server = require('mongodb').Server,
    CollectionDriver = require('./collectionDriver').CollectionDriver;

var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

var mongoHost = 'localHost';
var mongoPort = 27017;
var collectionDriver;

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mongo-server';
// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(error, db) {
  if (error) {
    console.error("Unable to connect to MongoDB. Please make sure mongod is running on %s.", url);
    process.exit(1);
  }

  console.log("Connected to MongoDB successfully.");
  collectionDriver = new CollectionDriver(db);
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>');
});

app.get('/:collection', function(req, res) {
   var params = req.params;
   collectionDriver.findAll(req.params.collection, function(error, objs) {
          if (error) { res.send(400, error); }
          else {
              if (req.accepts('html')) {
                  res.render('data',{objects: objs, collection: req.params.collection});
              } else {
              res.set('Content-Type','application/json');
                  res.send(200, objs);
              }
         }
    });
});

app.get('/:collection/:entity', function(req, res) {
   var params = req.params;
   var entity = params.entity;
   var collection = params.collection;
   if (entity) {
       collectionDriver.get(collection, entity, function(error, objs) {
          if (error) { res.send(400, error); }
          else { res.send(200, objs); }
       });
   } else {
      res.send(400, {error: 'bad url', url: req.url});
   }
});

app.post('/:collection', function(req, res) {
    var object = req.body;
    var collection = req.params.collection;
    collectionDriver.save(collection, object, function(err,docs) {
          if (err) { res.send(400, err); }
          else { res.send(201, docs); }
     });
});

app.put('/:collection/:entity', function(req, res) {
    var params = req.params;
    var entity = params.entity;
    var collection = params.collection;
    if (entity) {
       collectionDriver.update(collection, req.body, entity, function(error, objs) {
          if (error) { res.send(400, error); }
          else { res.send(200, objs); }
       });
   } else {
       var error = { "message" : "Cannot PUT a whole collection" }
       res.send(400, error);
   }
});

app.delete('/:collection/:entity', function(req, res) {
    var params = req.params;
    var entity = params.entity;
    var collection = params.collection;
    if (entity) {
       collectionDriver.delete(collection, entity, function(error, objs) {
          if (error) { res.send(400, error); }
          else { res.send(200, objs); }
       });
   } else {
       var error = { "message" : "Cannot DELETE a whole collection" }
       res.send(400, error);
   }
});

app.use(function (req,res) {
    res.render('404', {url:req.url});
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

I am new to MongoDB.

Comment: Are you run `MongoDB` before run `node index.js`

Comment: Can you change your console.error message to output the actual error message, at least to debug?  Odds are the mongodb server isn't running or there's a firewall in place blockng it, or it requires auth.  But you'll know more if you log the error.

Comment: @Paul, how to do this? I am so new here :)

Comment: You have code that says, `    console.error("Unable to connect to MongoDB. Please make sure mongod is running on %s.", url);`.  Change it to read, `console.error(error.message)`

Comment: It says: `failed to connect to [localhost:27017]`

Comment: @Khuong `failed to connect to [localhost:27017]` You need to install and run MongoDB

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- first Start Mongo Server
  step for that
- C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin
- now write `mongod`
- after running successfully you will see this output

My code for connection

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    format = require('util').format;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        console.log("successfully connected to the database");
    }
    db.close();
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

make sure to start your mongo server from your terminal or command prompt.

Follow the below steps to start the server:

1. if mongodb is not installed, install it from https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community.
2. you have to create a new directory in your c folder with name called data and inside data create one more directoy called db. These folders are required for your mongodb to save data.
3. now open terminal or command prompt, navigate inside the bin folder residing in your mongodb folder and enter mongod. this will start your server.